# How to upgrade MVC 3 project to .NET 4.5 [NOT to MVC 4]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.5

How to upgrade MVC 3 project to .NET 4.5?
Which assemblies should I update?

I've change
     `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

but still it's not enough.

Comment: What makes you think it's not enough?

Comment: I've had conflicts with libraries.

Comment: You should strongly consider moving to a new version of MVC if you're going to be targeting .NET 4.5.  MVC 4 has some additional bug fixes and other tweaks that make it more stable and efficient than MVC 3 when running on 4.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which assemblies should I update?

You should not update any assemblies. Just change the Target Framework in the properties of your MVC project:

[image]